# fancybox 3: custom settings not taking effect

Tags: jquery, load, fancybox, customization, fancybox-3

I have a html file, inside is `<div class="gallery"> </div>`. I'm loading files/img using a jquery function `load()`

```
$(".gallery").load("gallery/photos.php");
```

inside .php code is:

```
$photoDir = '../gallery/foto';
       
$photoFiles = array_diff(scandir($photoDir,1), array('..', '.'));
        
foreach($photoFiles as $photoFiles)
    echo '<a href="gallery/glamour/'.$photoFiles.'" data-fancybox="images" ><img src="gallery/glamour/'.$photoFiles.'"></a>';
```

and fancybox work with default settings but when I want to call my settings it doesn't work, for example I use:

```
$("[data-fancybox="images"]").fancybox({
thumbs : {
    autoStart : true
},   
keyboard: false,
});
```

I tried global way from documentation:

```
$.fancybox.defaults.animationEffect = "tube";
```

but it did not work either... but when I disable my `load()` and in `.gallery` div I write (hardcode):

```
<a href="gallery/photo/img1.jpg" data-fancybox="images" ><img src="gallery/photo/img1.jpg"></a>
```

then my custom settings work fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your selector returns your links.

In your case, replace `$("[data-fancybox]")` with `$('[data-fancybox="images"]')`

Comment: yes, my fault, i past wrong (old) code... i tried different selectors it dint work..

Comment: How can we know what you tried and what is the actual output of your php code?

Comment: because i write " yes, my fault, i past wrong (old) code"... what is unclear in "yes, my fault"?...  to this topic i copy/paste old code ( i tried meany things )... so, in php is data-fancybox="images"  and in jq is $('[data-fancybox="images"]')... is this answer is unclear alsow?

Comment: No, it is not clear if you managed to solve your issue or not.

Comment: yes i'm able to solve this by myself that why i started this topic in first place..

Comment: If you wanted to chat, you could just have used gitter - https://gitter.im/fancyapps/fancybox

Comment: yes i wanted to chat that why i start asking a philosophical questions.. ou wait, ups...